# Jasperserver conditional statement

Tags: jasperserver

I want to change some jsp pages in jasperserver,
and all my need to know is :

the logged user, have ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR or not ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tag **`authz:authorize`** in jsp file.

The example:

```html
<authz:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
```

Or you can use condition in configuration files (xml) like in this sample:

```html
<condition test="checkAuthenticationRoles" testArgs="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
```

The snippet from *decoratorCommonComponents.jsp* file:

```html
<authz:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
    <li id="main_logOut" class="last"><a id="main_logOut_link" href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;"><spring:message code="menu.logout"/></a></li>
</authz:authorize>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it dosn't work ,
that's what I tried to do :
 in the file results.jsp (modules/search)
I have :

<div>
...
</div>

and don't need that div be displayed if the user haven't administrator role only

so I tried 
<authz:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
<div>...</div>
</authz:authorized>

and I tried also

<condition test="checkAuthenticationRoles" testArgs="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
<div>...</div>
</condition>

But it dosen't work

I use jasperserver 4.5

Comment: You might need to add `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz"%>` to the page so that it recognizes the authz prefix.

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what I don't put :)
I will ask you again if I have another problem. 
thanks again ;-)